# Why is Typhoon Neoguri sometimes referred to as "ノグリー"?

Tags: etymology, loanwords, spelling

Why is Typhoon Neoguri sometimes referred to in Japanese as "ノグリー", and not as "ネオグリー"?

The English language Wikipedia's disambiguation page for [Typhoon Neoguri](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typhoon_Neoguri) mentions that it used to be referred to in English as "Noguri", but that was back in 2002, and there's been another Typhoon Neoguri between then and now.

Is it because Japanese has a commonly used transliteration of the Korean word for "Raccoon dog" ([너구리](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%EB%84%88%EA%B5%AC%EB%A6%AC))?

Comment: http://www.nongshimusa.com/layouts/nongshim/images/img_prd_noodle_04.jpg

Comment: Because that's how it is [pronounced](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Romanization_of_Korean)?

Comment: Moral: Not all romanisations have transparent pronunciations.

Comment: **Romanization is not transcription.**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My assumption would be that neoguri is one way of romanizing the hangul 너구리, but that the pronunciation is closer to "noguri." Given the tendency of katakana to go with pronunciation, it would be ノグリー. Listen to the Korean [here](http://www.forvo.com/word/%EB%84%88%EA%B5%AC%EB%A6%AC/#ko).

Comment: Yes, *eo* is a transliteration of ㅓ, a romanization intended to represent the writing system, like if you wrote *watasiha* for Japanese わたしは.  Although *ŏ* is a transcription, intended to more closely reflect pronunciation, the diacritic ˘ is commonly omitted, making it ambiguous (cf. Japanese *Tokyo* versus *Tōkyō*).  In Martin's romanization system, used mainly by linguists, it's *e* instead.

Comment: The romanization system for Korean that uses "*e*" for ㅓ is also known as [Yale romanization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yale_romanization_of_Korean).  It was developed to provide a more one-to-one correspondence between the romanization and the hangul, with the downside that the romanized spellings sometimes diverge from the expected sound from an English speaker's perspective.  There is also  [McCune–Reischauer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/McCune%E2%80%93Reischauer), using "*ŏ*" for ㅓ, and [Revised](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revised_Romanization_of_Korean), using "*eo*" for ㅓ.

Comment: @EiríkrÚtlendi Martin's romanization isn't a system of transliteration, so it's not intended to provide a one-to-one correspondence.  It transcribes several features that aren't generally transcribed in Hangul.

Comment: From your description, it sounds like Martin is using something *like* Yale, but that isn't Yale.  I'm not familiar with Martin -- who is this?

Comment: @EiríkrÚtlendi The creator of Yale Romanization and the author of *A Reference Grammar of Japanese* and *A Reference Grammar of Korean*.  He was a student of the structuralist Bloch, alongside Jorden.